# Google Map shows at the corner in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have code for Google Maps that was working perfectly, but now my map is showing in the one corner the remaining portion greyed out. I have searched in Google for a solution, but found nothing. I tried to inspect in chrome, for any CSS issues. I just right clicked in Chrome and clicked *Inspect element*, and surprisingly my Google maps shows correctly, when I reload page, it only partially shows.

This is my complete code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 6,
center: latlng
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
var center = map.getCenter();
map.setCenter(center);
}
function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById('t35').value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: results[0].geometry.location
});
} else {
  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
}
} );
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
var center = map.getCenter();
map.setCenter(center);
</script>
```

I tried below code :

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

And another one :

```
var center = map.getCenter();
map.setCenter(center);
```

Nothing is working, any advice.

Comment: I assume the map initially is not fully visible, how do you show the map?

Comment: @Dr. Molle. Yes, now initially not fully visible, if I enter location in text box and called function coreaddress I can see the correct location but not fully, shows partially. So both time map shows partially.

Comment: Where is the code that does that?